# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k$ exists and is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequences of real numbers. Suppose that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $m\geq n \geq N$ implies $\left|\sum\limits_{k=n}^m x_k\right| < \epsilon$. Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k$$ exists and is finite.

*Demostración:* Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $m,n \ge N\in\mathbb N$ and let $S_N = \sum\limits_{k=0}^N x_k$ denote the $N$-th partial sum of the series. Then we see that the series above is a Cauchy series because
$$|S_m-S_n |= \left| \sum_{k=1}^mx_k - \sum_{k=1}^nx_k \right| = \left| \sum_{k=n}^mx_k \right| < \epsilon.$$
Then we have that there exists $N \in\mathbb N$ such that when $m\ge n\ge N$, we have
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^nx_k - \sum_{k=1}^mx_k \right| < \epsilon$$
because $\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^mx_k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k \right| =\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^mx_k \right|$ by theorem.

Questions:

- Is this a complete proof?
- Better yet, is this how I would prove this?
- Am I missing something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sequence of the partial sums is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers thus it is convergent.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani, So if everything I have done so far is correct, I just need to add in that statement at the end?

Comment: Yes, it is a well-known theorem.